# Linux dask-worker cannot connect to windows dask-scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I've started `dask-scheduler` on windows

Now I attempt to run `dask-worker <ip>:<port>` in ec2 instance.

I've been thrown at the following error:

```
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://10.34.33.12:36525'
distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory '/dask-worker-space/worker-v_5Vmm', purging
distributed.nanny - ERROR - Failed to start worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 541, in run
    yield worker._start(*worker_start_args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 260, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 425, in _start
    self.start_services(listen_host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 368, in start_services
    self.services[k] = v(self, io_loop=self.loop, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/bokeh/worker.py", line 634, in __init__
    main = Application(FunctionHandler(partial(main_doc, worker, extra)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/function.py", line 11, in __init__
    _check_callback(func, ('doc',))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/callback_manager.py", line 12, in _check_callback
    sig = signature(callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/future.py", line 85, in signature
    for name in func.keywords.keys():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
distributed.nanny - INFO - Closing Nanny at 'tcp://10.34.33.12:36525'
distributed.dask_worker - INFO - End worker
```

Can you tell me what is happening?
Is it even possible for dask to connect to a machine for making a cluster with different os?

Comment: What version of Python, Dask, and Bokeh are you running?